# Angular 2 - Filtering a Array Object not working

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to implement a filter in Angular 2 class, but i'm getting an error for some reason. I'm not able to filter and return the results.

Class code:

```
employee = [
    { "empId": "59C", "empDesc": "Software","location":"Dallas"},
    { "empId": "AMI", "empDesc": "Hardware", "location":"San Francisco"}
  ];
  companies : any = [];
  comapny : any = [];
  test:string="varun";
  companyId = this.employee[0].empId;
  constructor(){
    for (let c of this.employee) {
      this.companies.push({
        empDesc: c.empDesc,
        empId: c.empId
      })
    };
   console.log("Companies",this.companies);
  }
  getCompanies(companies){
    if (this.companyId) {
                  var filtered = companies.filter(function (company) {
                      return company.companyId === this.companyId;
                  });

                  return filtered[0];
              }

  }

  this.company = this.getCompanies(this.companies);
  console.log("Filtered company", this.company);
```

Plunker link

https://plnkr.co/edit/CnBR4JouNhzH3DWm7QCo?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

always run your code in the constructor, also company has no  `companyId`,this gonna work :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <ul><li *ngFor="let c of companies">{{c.empId}} - {{c.empDesc}}</li></ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
   employee = [
    { "empId": "59C", "empDesc": "Software","location":"Dallas"},
    { "empId": "AMI", "empDesc": "Hardware", "location":"San Francisco"}
  ];
  companies : any = [];
  comapny : any = [];
  test:string="varun";
  companyId = this.employee[0].empId;
  constructor(){
    for (let c of this.employee) {
      this.companies.push({
        empDesc: c.empDesc,
        empId: c.empId
      })
    };
   console.log("Companies",this.companies);
   this.company = this.getCompanies(this.companies);
  console.log("Filtered company", this.company);
  }
  getCompanies(companies){
    let self = this;
    if (this.companyId) {
                  var filtered = companies.filter(function (company) {
                       return company.empId === self.companyId;
                  });

                  return filtered[0];
              }

  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But, why did we use, let self = this; in the function? And the function is not working when I replace self with this in "return company.empId === self.companyId;". Can you tell me why that's happening?

Comment: because if we used `this` it will refer to the `companies`  array which has no `comanyId` field. in other words `this` of the class will be shadowed by `this` of the `companies` array in its filter method.

Answer (score 3):

Your plunker does not work. Your pboblem is with the two last lines:

```
this.company = this.getCompanies(this.companies);

console.log("Filtered company", this.company);
```

You shouldn't call methods or console.log directly in classes. You need to put this thing inside your constructor. Like:

```
employee = [
  { "empId": "59C", "empDesc": "Software","location":"Dallas"},
  { "empId": "AMI", "empDesc": "Hardware", "location":"San Francisco"}
];
companies : any = [];
comapny : any = [];
test:string="varun";
companyId = this.employee[0].empId;
constructor(){
  for (let c of this.employee) {
    this.companies.push({
      empDesc: c.empDesc,
      empId: c.empId
    })
  };
  this.company = this.getCompanies(this.companies);
  console.log("Filtered company", this.company);
  console.log("Companies",this.companies);
}
getCompanies(companies){
  if (this.companyId) {
                var filtered = companies.filter(function (company) {
                    return company.empId === this.companyId;
                });

                return filtered[0];
            }

}
```

Comment: And a `company` in `companies` didn't have a field called `companyId`.(only `empId`) And maybe he should use `Array.find` instead of `Array.filter` in his case.

Comment: And please please.. use arrow functions as callbacks.. that will prevent a lot of 'this' confusion in your code..